# Under what circumstances may the noun 'ambush' not be preceded by any article?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, contemporary-english

In particular, I wish to know if *they were attacked from ambush* and *they were attacked from an ambush* are equally in fashion. The articled form is is definitely more familiar, but look at the first definition in https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waylay .

Might one say that the unarticled usage is passé ? Please cite current usage examples if you can.

Comment: I don't think there is a strong reason to treat _ambush_ separately as regards the use/omission of articles. It is the same as it is with other common nouns.

Comment: What precise general rule applies here ? Do please gratify me.

Comment: I'd rather see *by ambush*.

Comment: "taken by ambush", "lying in ambush", etc, are common idioms, similar in format to "taken by stealth" or "obtained by deception". As others say, I don't think "from ambush" or "from an ambush" are particularly idiomatic in modern English, but other constructions with or without an article would work.

Comment: That was some ambush!